# Updating ror 1.8.7 to 1.9.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I'm a beginner ror programmer with a macbook air. i've just managed to upgrade my leopard to Lion. Downloaded codex 10.7 and macport and also RVM. The thing i'm trying to do now is to update my ruby from 1.8.7 to 1.9.3 but this is what i got:

I typed out: 'rvm install ruby-1.9.2-p318"

Annie-Tungs-MacBook-Air:~ annietung$ rvm install ruby-1.9.2-p318 Fetching yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/annietung/.rvm/archives Extracting yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/annietung/.rvm/src Configuring yaml in /Users/annietung/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4. Error running ' ./configure --prefix="/Users/annietung/.rvm/usr" ', please read /Users/annietung/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p318/yaml/configure.log Compiling yaml in /Users/annietung/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4. Error running 'make ', please read /Users/annietung/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p318/yaml/make.log
Database file /Users/annietung/.rvm/config/packages does not exist.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/annietung/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.2-p318 - #fetching ruby-1.9.2-p318 - #extracted to /Users/annietung/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p318 (already extracted) ruby-1.9.2-p318 - #configuring Error running ' ./configure --prefix=/Users/annietung/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318 --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --with-libyaml --with-opt-dir=/Users/annietung/.rvm/usr ', please read /Users/annietung/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p318/configure.log There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation. ls: /Users/annietung/.rvm/rubies/*/bin/ruby: No such file or directory Annie-Tungs-MacBook-Air:~ annietung$

Comment: if you're Bryan, who's Annie Tung then?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to download and install [Apple's Command Line Tools](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action) for OSX Lion so that you can build Ruby properly.

Comment: i just downloaded xcode lion 4.1 but there seems to be a problem. I need to uninstall xcode 4... do you know how to do that?

Comment: i've also typed this into the terminal but there was no reaction:

sudo <Xcode>/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all

Comment: You don't need to install XCode in it's entirety, you can just install the command line tools if you want.  However, you should be able to install newer versions of XCode over older versions without any problems.  Are there any particular error messages you're getting?